# Game in linux terminal: Changing images: printing over already printed text

Tags: c, linux, bash, console, printf

Well, I'm simply implementing pretty easy card game in linux terminal.
What I want to achieve is an effect of changing images, basically trick printing over already printed text(which I guess I cannot do except reprinting same line with \r).

What I was thinking to do is to get the terminal height, and then print newlines till the lower edge of the terminal, then position the cursor in terminal, so that the last line printed would be on top.

Are there any nice ways to do this? I've just found library called [Ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). Seems it can do that. Is it a good option?

Comment: Ncurses creates its own character window in the terminal and allows you to acces and overwrite characters at specific positions. This looks perfect for your game, where you can draw character-art cards anywhere on the screen. Way better than emulating the same by scrolling () the terminal, anyway.

Comment: Curses is the best option, as compatible libraries are available for all operating systems (including Windows command line); ncurses is the best one for Linux. For Linux and Unix terminals, you can also use [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes), often called [terminal codes](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes). For example, printing `"\033[2;3H"` will move the cursor to the third column on the second row, counting from top. Anyway, I do recommend using Curses anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ncurses creates its own character window in the terminal and allows you to acces and overwrite characters at specific positions. This looks perfect for your game, where you can draw character-art cards anywhere on the screen. Way better than emulating the same by scrolling () the terminal, anyway. –  M Oehm

Curses is the best option, as compatible libraries are available for all operating systems (including Windows command line); ncurses is the best one for Linux. For Linux and Unix terminals, you can also use [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes), often called [terminal codes](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes). For example, printing `"\033[2;3H"` will move the cursor to the third column on the second row, counting from top. Anyway, I do recommend using Curses anyway. –  Nominal Animal